# Hide a Page Temporarily

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page

We have a campaign page created in our site . Now we need to hide the page temporarily for few days . How do i do that in a publishing site?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the permissions in the page for everyone except for the farm administrator.

Comment: This is an anonymous site

Comment: Then delete the file. So it will go to the recycle bin. Then restore when needed back. Else you can download a copy and delete the file.

Comment: Or, unpublish it

Comment: If you unpublish it, approvers can see. Which means still there will be few users who can see.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to some other page using JavaScript

```
window.location="http://www.site.com/home";
```

OR

using css also can hide the contents

```
.body {   
    display:none;    
}
```

Comment: @Thomson let us know what you think?